# Conditional Background of a plot in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot, background

I just want to know how to do this kind of conditional colored background. The condition might be calculated by this timeseries or another one.
For instance, I have two timeseries. When the value of the first one is positive, the value of the background on the second plot is green, otherwise it's red.

[image]

Comment: This might he helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794699/dynamic-background-in-plot-based-on-x-axis-values

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one way to do it.

```
x <- 1:100
t1 <- rnorm(100)
t2 <- rnorm(100)
plot(x, t2, type="n")
abline(v=x, col=c("red", "green")[(t2>0)+1])
lines(x, t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

rasterImage is probably the right tool,

```
x <- seq(0,10,length=30)
y <- jitter(sin(x),a=0.1)
grad <- scales::rescale(y^2, to = c(0.5,0.1))
plot(x, y, type="n", xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
rasterImage(t(hsv(h = grad, s = 1, v = 0.8)), 
            xleft = min(x), ybottom = min(y),
            xright = max(x), ytop = max(y))
lines(x,y)
```

[image]